# Why onNewIntent is invoked twice from SearchActivity?

Tags: android

I am using **SearchView** to handles search in the app. Whenever search happens from the **SearchActivity** the **onNewIntent** method is invoked twice. Though if search is done from other activities then onNewIntent will be invoked just once.

Why onNewIntent is invoked twice from SearchActivity?

Here is the relevant code & configuration from the app.

**Manifest**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchResultsActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SearchActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.browse.BrowseActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
```

**onCreateOptionsMenu** of all activities

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(this, SearchActivity.class)));
    searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search_hint));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**SearchActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);
    Toolbar toolBar = findViewById(R.id.searchActivityToolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    handleSearch(intent); // perform search
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is a bug in Android Emulators, which causes an extra *onNewIntent* for search functionality implemented using **SearchView**.

This behavior does not occur on real devices.